# eth-brownie installation fails

Tags: python, brownie

I tried installing eth-brownie and when I execute `brownie --version` in terminal I get this

```
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/bin/brownie", line 5, in <module>
    from brownie._cli.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from brownie.project import compile_source, run
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import (  # NOQA 401
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from brownie.network import web3
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/network/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .account import Accounts
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .rpc import Rpc
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from brownie.network.state import Chain
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/network/state.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .transaction import TransactionReceipt
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 15, in <module>
    import black
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .regex import *
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/regex/regex.py", line 419, in <module>
    import regex._regex_core as _regex_core
  File "/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import regex._regex as _regex
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so: code signature in (/Users/yourlogarithm/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library
```

I followed the installation guide from here: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by reinstalling `regex` via `pip`:

1. Type in console `pip uninstall regex`
2. Type `pip install regex`